# Is it possible to get the source of code of this java script without running it DONT PASTE IN YOUR BROSWER

Tags: javascript

not trying to get anyone to run this i simply want to know what it does as someone tried to get me to go here on facebook

eztop-viewers.tk/working.js

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like `wget` which will down load into a file and do nothing else.

Comment: My antivirus kills the connection when i try that

Comment: @anonymous: then tell your AV to ignore `wget` (or get a better AV).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Telnet client installed on your machine, you can retrieve the script through it. At a command prompt, enter: `telnet eztop-viewers.tk 80`.

Then, enter the following (note there are two returns at the end):

```
GET /working.js HTTP/1.1
Host: eztop-viewers.tk
```

This should return the script in your command prompt window, without executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great question for SO IMHO, in any case here are two ways:

**in your chrome browser**, type:

```
view-source:http://eztop-viewers.tk/working.js
```

firefox should be similar

**from a shell** download the file

```
wget http://eztop-viewers.tk/working.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open Notepad...  go to File->Open... and enter there http://*filelink*

should work.